# Setting up PTP (Precision Time Protocol) in virtual RHEL 6/Centos 6 environment

Tags: ntp

I'm trying to use VirtualBox to simulate establishment of a PTP network in order to test/integrate some new software being developed.

Unfortunately, ntpd and chronyd are NOT supported as time sources.

I understand that I have no PTP clock to sync with and am trying to use the software clock (i.e. local virtual system) instead.

The ptp4l command is being invoked as:

```
 ptp4l -f /etc/ptp4l.conf -S -L -l 7 -i eth0
```

And I get the response of:

```
 interface 'eth0' does not support requested timestamping mode.
```

What am I missing in making my virtual PTP "lab" a reality using internal clocks?

Answer (score 1):

Loose the `-L` flag.  This is to "Select the legacy hardware time stamping." which conflicts with the `-S` flag which is to "Select the software time stamping."  See https://linux.die.net/man/8/ptp4l or use `man ptp4l` command for more info.